# How to make menu item rounded

Tags: menu

Hy, guys :)
I want to styling my Ubuntu specifically in unity all context and global menu.
I want to change it rounded like Mac's menu like this :

[image]

How can make it like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking through the themes over at gnome-look.org anything under the "GTK3" category in theory will work with both Unity and Gnome-shell. This rule should also work for icons as well.

References:

[Gnome Look](http://gnome-look.org/)

[Good reference info from the Ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1971094)